# Change config values in appsettings.json GitHubActions

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, github-actions, github-actions-artifacts

I am struggling to replace values in my `appsettings.json` file and was wondering where I'm going wrong?

I have created two secrets in GitHub entitled `COSMOSDBSETTINGS_SERVICEENDPOINT` and `COSMOSDBSETTINGS_AUTHKEY`.

```
      - name: Publish
        run: dotnet publish -c Release -o ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp

      - name: App Settings Variable Substitution
        uses: microsoft/variable-substitution@v1
        with:
          files: '${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}\myapp\appsettings.json'
        env:
          CosmosDbSettings:ServiceEndpoint: ${{ secrets.COSMOSDBSETTINGS_SERVICEENDPOINT }}
          CosmosDbSettings:AuthKey: ${{ secrets.COSMOSDBSETTINGS_AUTHKEY }}
```

I get the error stating

```
Run microsoft/variable-substitution@v1
Applying variable substitution on JSON file: C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\dotnet\myapp\appsettings.json
Skipped updating file: C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\dotnet\myapp\appsettings.json
Error: Error: Failed to apply variable substitution
```

This is the `appsettings` locally:

```
  "CosmosDbSettings": {
    "ServiceEndpoint": "https://localhost:8081/",
    "AuthKey": "KEY"
  },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a dot instead of a colon:

```yaml
env:
  CosmosDbSettings.ServiceEndpoint: ${{ secrets.COSMOSDBSETTINGS_SERVICEENDPOINT }}
  CosmosDbSettings.AuthKey: ${{ secrets.COSMOSDBSETTINGS_AUTHKEY }}
```